# React i18next::backendConnector issue whenever I change the namespace

Tags: reactjs, i18next, react-i18next

-**hello**, I've learned **i18n** yesterday, everything works fine but I get an issue whenever I change the namespace of the locale file from **translation.json** to **otherNameSpace.json**, I always get this message on the browser console:

**i18next::backendConnector: loading namespace translation for language en failed failed parsing /locales/en/translation.json to json**

here's my files structure
[image]

my file **i18n.js:**

```
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';
import Backend from 'i18next-http-backend';

i18n.use(Backend)
    .use(LanguageDetector)
    .use(initReactI18next)
    .init({
        debug: true,
        fallbackLng: "en"
    })

export default i18n;
```

and here's the file where I used useTranslation hook where I gave the name of my namespace **header.js**:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

export const Header = () => {
   const { t, i18n } = useTranslation("header");

   // on change the language
   const changeLanguage = (e) => {
      const newLange = e.currentTarget.value;
      i18n.changeLanguage(newLange)
   }

   return (
      <> 
      <select defaultValue={ localStorage.getItem("i18nextLng") || "en"} 
      className='select_lang' onChange={changeLanguage}>
         <option value="en">En</option>
         <option value="fr">Fr</option>
      </select>
      // I make translation on this button and some other elements
      <button className='btnLoginHeader'>{t("loginBtn")}</button>
      </>
   );
}
```

can someone tell me what I need to search for or what I need to learn to solve this issue? thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default i18next sets the ns and defaultNS option to `'translation'`
https://www.i18next.com/overview/configuration-options#languages-namespaces-resources
[image]

If you do not have that namespace, set those options to a different value, i.e.:

```
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';
import Backend from 'i18next-http-backend';

i18n.use(Backend)
    .use(LanguageDetector)
    .use(initReactI18next)
    .init({
        debug: true,
        fallbackLng: "en",
        ns: ["header"],
        defaultNS: "header"
    })

export default i18n;
```

Additionally, make sure your translations files are valid JSONs.

btw: If you don't want to manage your translation files manually or are simply looking for a better management solution, take a look at [i18next-locize-backend](https://github.com/locize/i18next-locize-backend).